# Deploying multiple WSP files using a single setup - SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, wsp

Is there a tool or method/process to create a package which installs multiple WSP files using a single setup for both SharePoint 2007 and SharePoint 2010?

Comment: As far is i know, the usual setup routines can only install 1 wsp package. I'd use a *.bat script for this purpose, but i don't know if this is within your requirements.

Comment: Yes. I wrote a custom one to meet the needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any setup tool out there which can deploy multiple wsps. So I wrote a custom setup to deploy them.